# How to tell if moment date object date fragment value is implicit or explicit?

Tags: momentjs

I am parsing a string that contains date in it and I want to know whether it contains a specific fragment of the date (e.g. year, month, etc).

I have looked into the documentation and into the resulting object, e.g.

[image: DD MMMM]

In the above example, the subject input contains only information about day and month. Year value is derived from the current time.

Looking at the output/using [moment](/questions/tagged/moment) API, how can I tell whether the year value is explicit (was parsed from the subject string using format) or implicit ([moment](/questions/tagged/moment) assumes current `new Date()` value to fill in the gaps)?

Comment: Relevant issue https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2672

Comment: This isn't a feature moment.js currently offers.  We can discuss this feature request in the issue you logged.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a feature request, which the OP has already logged to the project's issue tracker.

Comment: This is not a feature request because it can be done outside of `moment`. I have solved the issue by writing a higher level function that wraps `moment` and that analyses the format input to determine wether the produced date fragments are implicit or explicit.

Comment: Ah, then feel free to post your function here as an answer. If it's good - I'll vote for it. :)